# Deleting games from iPhone 5s and ipad

Tags: iphone

If I delete a game from my Game Center on my iPad, will it delete the game off of my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the game account is bound to your apple id. Seen as though the game center syncs,You will loze the data on all devices!